# What is the simple way to extract a JSON string from a Microsoft DynamicJsonObject?

Tags: c#, javascript, json

When using the Microsoft namespaces `System.Web.Helpers` and `System.Web.Script.Serialization` I expected that the Microsoft serializer played well with Microsofts dynamic JSON object. It turns out that this was a naive assumption. The JavaScriptSerializer serializes the object to "{}". What is the recommended way for this seemingly trivial task?

```
     dynamic obj = new DynamicJsonObject(new Dictionary<string,object>());
     obj.FirstName = "Henry";
     obj.LastName = "Ford";
     JavaScriptSerializer jsc = new JavaScriptSerializer();
     string str = jsc.Serialize( obj );
     Assert.AreNotEqual(str, "{}"); // Does not fail
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/)

```
dynamic obj = new DynamicJsonObject(new Dictionary<string,object>());
obj.FirstName = "Henry";
obj.LastName = "Ford";
string str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
```

It will do it successfully. You can use it with anonymous classes

```
string s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {FirstName="Henry",LastName="Ford"});
```

and `ExpandoObject`s too

```
dynamic obj = new ExpandoObject();
obj.FirstName = "Henry";
obj.LastName = "Ford";
string s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
```

Deserialization to dynamic objects is also possible

```
dynamic obj2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(@"{""FirstName"":""Henry"",""LastName"":""Ford""}");
Console.WriteLine(obj2.FirstName + " " + obj2.LastName);
```

Comment: Does Json.Net provide an alternative to DynamicJsonObject or should I use the System.Web.Helpers implementation? I'm not to impressed with the things I find under System.Web

Comment: I'll mark as answered when and if it is concluded that the Microsoft parts are broken (or 'in a mess' as the case may be).

Comment: @JackWester, I am not sure I understand your question since you don't need `DynamicJsonObject` to work with dynamic objects. I updated the answer showing how to use `ExpandoObject` for this purpose – L.B 11 mins ago

Comment: @LB, I thought the DynamicJsonObject would provide Json functionality. The Javascript Object Notation (Json) generated by other classes in the System namespace does not generate Json for DynamicJsonObject. So you are right, I don't need it. Actually, I think that these new classes are poured over users instead of going through careful scrutinization. I'll stay clear of these namespaces.